# Import Helper Class in Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'd like to import a helper class rather than inlining the logic inside my component. I get the following error:

```
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars  'NavbarService' is defined but never used
```

---

**/services/NavbarService.js**

```
class NavbarService {
  constructor (init) {
    this.init = init;
  }

  static applications () {
    return [
      { name: 'Administration' },
      { name: 'Standard' }
    ];
  }

  static views () {
    return [
      { name: 'Providers', path: '/providers' },
      { name: 'Authorities', path: '/authorities' },
      { name: 'Services', path: '/services' },
      { name: 'Codes', path: '/codes' }
    ];
  }
}
```

**/components/Navbar.vue**

```
import NavbarService from '../services/NavbarService.js';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      versionIsVisible: false,
      version: '2.0.0',
      applications: NavbarService.applications(),
      views: NavbarService.views()
    };
  },

  methods: {
    showApplications: function () {
      this.applications = NavbarService.applications();
      this.views = [];

      return;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Does anything ever instantiate the class, or is it purely a container for helper functions?

Comment: Purely a container.

Comment: I think you don't want a class, then. Can you make it a plain object?

Comment: That works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Roy J's suggestion, I changed **/services/NavbarService.js** to:

```
export default {
  applications: function () {
    return [
      { name: 'Administration' },
      { name: 'Standard' }
    ];
  },

  views: function () {
    return [
      { name: 'Providers', path: '/providers' },
      { name: 'Authorities', path: '/authorities' },
      { name: 'Services', path: '/services' },
      { name: 'Codes', path: '/codes' }
    ];
  }
};
```